# Unable to modify the Jenkins Freestyle jobs and also the configuration page is also scattered after the Jenkins version upgrade

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins Version :- 2.319.1

I have upgraded Jenkins to 2.319.1 and after the upgrade now I am trying to make some modification in the freestyle job but the configuration page is scattered. Also, after making the changes when I try to click on "Apply and Save" button no action is performed from the Jenkins side. It doesn't save the changes while clicking on the "Apply and Save" button. No Error is displayed while trying to Apply the changes or trying to Save the changes in the Freestyle Jobs.

Was trying to modify the Old Freestyle jobs created on the previous Jenkins version and it should have allowed me to make the changes in the jobs but its not allowing me to make any modification to the existing jobs and also the UI is scattered for Freestyle Jobs configuration page.

Comment: From what version? < 2.263.4 ? Did you read the [Upgrade Guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.277/#configuration-form-modernization), specifically related to tables-to-divs upgrade, but all the [Upgrade Guides](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/#jenkins-lts-upgrade-guide) are good reading.

Comment: Previous version "2.252".

Comment: 100% guarantee [tables-to-divs issue](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/views/table-to-div-migration/). Follow all the instructions to diagnose and fix. It's been [2 years since the release](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/11/10/major-changes-in-weekly-releases/) so someone probably identified your specific case already.